# Find an integer pair in a range satisfying a specific ratio

Tags: rational-numbers, integers, ratio

I am trying to convert an image(*width*height*) to a smaller one whose width is between 45 and 55, keeping its aspect ratio as possible.

**For example:**

I have an original image whose size is 966*644, so its aspect ratio is 0.666...

And then, I want to convert this image to a smaller one whose width is between 45 and 55.

One possible solution is 50*33. Its ratio is 0.66. It is so close to the origin ratio but not enough.

The best-fit size is 51*34, because its aspect ratio is 0.666...

**So..**

Is there any formula or ideas to solve this problem?

I know, sometimes there is no integer solution. Then I want to get the best-fit integer pair.

Comment: Why not just try all 11 possible widths?

Comment: @GregMartin I will use this solution in web server, so calculating all 11 widths is too burdened.

Comment: It seems $45 \times 30$, $48 \times 32$, $51 \times 34$, $54\times 36$ all give the same aspect ratio in your particular example

Comment: @Henry Thats right. I showed a possible solution. What I need is generalized solution which can be used for any images.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are no good for my question. 
How do you find pairs of integers whose ratio is within a specified narrow range?
This occurs in the study of tuning systems in music, seeking an alternative to $12$-tone equal temperament. 
I want to find a pair of integers such that

$A/B < v/n < C/D\cdots  (1)$

where $v$ and $n$ are integers, with $v < n$
and $A/B = 4/7$ and $C/D = 3/5$.

I know that one solution is $v/n = 7/12$ and another one is $v/n = 18/31$.
What values of $n$ have an integer value of $v$ that satisfies $\cdots(1)$ ?

The solution is actually an infinite sequence of values for $n$, starting with those that have one favourable value for $v$, and continues as a sequence of finite sequences of $v$ for each succeeding value of $n$.

Are there any websites that cover this type of problem? I have no access to technical books, as I live far from any cities.

Comment: There's a nice section on rational approximation in Hardy and Wright that might be useful.  You might also look at literature on continued fractions.  However, if depends on how large you can tolerate $v$ and $f$ being.  If only relative small (e.g., less than 1000) numbers are useful to you, you'll be much better off writing some computer code to just do a brute-force search.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).